# Using TailwindCSS in a Django project hosted on Github

Tags: node.js, django, github, npm, tailwind-css

I want to use Django together with TailwindCSS in a personal web project and followed two instructions for setting it all up: on the one hand the installation instructions on

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation

on the other hand this Youtube tutorial (because the installation guide was too short for my limited understanding of the topic).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lsQVukhwpqQ

Since I am not familiar with node.js and npm, i am unsure how to store the resulting project in Github and reproduce it on other computers.  The structure of the Django project is no problem, I am familiar with it. I am unsure about the files and folders related to Tailwind and Node.
After the tutorial I had a "node_modules" and a "local-cdn" folder as well as "package.json" and "package-lock.json" and a "tailwind.config.js".

My question would be: which files present at the end of the two tutorials above should be synced with Github, which should not be synced and what to set up on a second machine (beyond installing node and django obvsly) to continue working on this already existing project there (in contrast to the tutorials above describing how to start a new project)?